# Why the DateFormat.format in jshell get different timezone code than in Wildfly Docker container and

Tags: docker, locale, java-11

I tried the following code in *jshell* and then in Wildfly Docker container

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.LONG, new Locale("es","ES"));
System.out.println("DEBUG:::" + df.format(new Date()));
```

In jshell, it prints: `jueves, abril 15, 2021 at 10:30:00 EEST`

Whereas when putting the code into a web app and then deploy to Wildfly Docker container, this prints in the backend: `sábado, 15 de julio de 2023, 22:33:43 UTC`

According to my understanding the end part of the timezone code should be the same, for instance `EEST`. But why in 2 different systems, I got different result?